# How retrieve the username to make a complete wall post using a Facebook dialog in an iPhone app?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm using this code to pop up a Facebook dialog and to allow the user to make a wall post, but the user name doesn't appear. I'd like that the post seemed like "USERNAME is using..."

```
Facebook *facebook = [[Facebook alloc] init];
SBJSON *jsonWriter = [SBJSON new];
NSDictionary* attachment = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:                
                    @"is using.... etc etc", @"name",
                    @"A caption", @"caption",
                    @"A description", @"description",
                                    nil];

NSString *attachmentStr = [jsonWriter stringWithObject:attachment];
NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                       API_KEY, @"api_key",
                                       @"Something to say", @"user_message_prompt",
                                       attachmentStr, @"attachment",
                                       nil];

[facebook dialog:@"stream.publish" andParams:params andDelegate:self];
```

This code works but before "is using...." nothing is printed. The user name doesn't appear.
I didn't succeeded in finding a sample, clear docs, to understand this. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the current user data by fetching the json object for "me"; graph.facebook.com/me

Comment: https://graph.facebook.com/me returns in some way a json object and I'm interested in the "name" field, but what method accepts this url? I'm confused

Comment: Usually the method is called simply "api", or you can just load that url and parse the json yourself.

Comment: I found how parse the json object, now I obtain    {
   error =     {
        message = "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.";
        type = OAuthException;
    };
} so I have to resolve this. Thank you for the hints :)

Comment: Yes, you need to log in to facebook first, and perhaps even call the api via the facebook lib (the api method).

Comment: I obtain this error also when the user is logged. He/she can post on his/her wall. I think I have to use the FBSession, but it seeems there is no FBSession api in facebook ios sdk